# Why does matrix multiplication run slower on work station with 7 cores than on my laptop?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I ran the following matlab code:

```
rng(1)
matrix_size = 200;
iterations = 100000;
A = rand(matrix_size);
B = rand(matrix_size);

profile on
for i = 1:iterations
  A * B;
end
profile off
```

On my MacAir (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4260U CPU @ 1.40GHz), this takes 39s. On a workstation with 7 cores (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2687W v4 @ 3.00GHz), this takes 62s.

I did not specify `-singleCompThread`. The work station has 12 cores, but there were 5 single-threaded processes running. I had (almost) 7 cores to myself. They were maxed out the whole time.

How can this be?

When running the above code with `-singleCompThread`, it completes in 54s.

Comment: You should run this test with specific matrices, not random matrices. The randomness could be a factor.

Comment: Note that the matrices are the same on both machines because of the `rng(1)`, which sets the seed.

Comment: what happens if you do the same test using [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html)? Try `f=@() for i=1:iterations; A*B; end;` then `t=timeit(f);`.

Comment: Are you *sure* matlab is required to have a standard implementation of `rand`? (In C and C++, the linear congruential coefficients are pretty much left to the implementation). Do consider checking that.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you explain why that would be significant? `rand` isn't part of the timing.

Comment: It might be a factor, and that's good enough for me.

Comment: A factor in *what*?

Comment: Do you use the same version of matlab?

Comment: It depends on the version of Matlab (BLAS and LAPACK versions), the OS you are using (may contain different library or driver), and other tasks the Xeon is running (scheduling may affect its performance). If it is really necessary could you run a `test` on both computers while they are completely idle?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a Mathworks support team [post](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958-which-matlab-functions-benefit-from-multithreaded-computation):

> As of MATLAB 7.4 (R2007a), MATLAB supports multithreaded computation
>   for a number of functions and expressions that are combinations of
>   element-wise functions (e.g. y=4*x*(sin(x) + x^3)). These functions
>   automatically execute on multiple threads and you do not need to
>   explicitly specify commands to create threads in your code.
>
> For a function or expression to execute faster (speed up) on multiple
>   cores, the following conditions must be true:
>
> 1) The operations in the algorithm carried out by the function are
>   easily partitioned into sections that can be executed concurrently,
>   and with little communication or few sequential operations required.
>   This is the case for all element-wise operations.
>
> 2) The data size is large enough so that any advantages of concurrent
>   execution outweigh the time required to partition the data and manage
>   separate execution threads. For example, most functions speed up only
>   when the array is greater than several thousand elements.
>
> 3) The operation is not memory-bound where the processing time is
>   dominated by memory access time, as is the case for simple operations
>   such as element-wise addition. As a general rule, more complex
>   functions speed up better than simple functions.

Your case does not fullfill 2. or 3. Multiplication is extremely fast and simple and is memory bound, and your matrices are relatively tiny. The multithreading would appear to include more overhead, as seen from your test with the -singleCompThread. You could try out the benchmark with a larger matrix and see if the difference changes. You could also try the benchmark on the Macbook with the -singleCompThread on to see whether the relative single thread performance falls into the expected range.

Another (partial) explanation could be the different vector instructions between Sandy Bridge and Haswell, i.e. [AVX2](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/157125-haswell-review-intels-core-i7-4770k-takes-over-the-pole-position). I'd do the benchmarks first before looking into that though.

Also note that the Matlab profiler turns off JIT. So the results you get might not be comparable to whatever real case you are benchmarking against.